# MySql chained queries

Tags: mysql, chained

I would like to run multiple queries on my database but i'd like to apply second query over the result of first query. I don't have much experience with databases so, please excuse me if this is a dumb question.

Example:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE table.column='criteria';
```

and over the result of the first query i'd like to apply another filter:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE table.column2='criteria2';
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Do you want to combine the results, or filter on multiple columns in the same table ?  Your question isn't clear.

Comment: I would like to filter on multiple columns in the same table

Comment: Ok, so my answer is correct. ;) For more information : http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/logical-operators.html#operator_and

Answer (score 2):

If you want to apply another filter :

```
SELECT * 
FROM table 
WHERE table.column='criteria'
AND table.column2='criteria2';
```

Comment: Look at the documentation if you want more informations : http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/logical-operators.html ;)

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
SELECT *  FROM table 
WHERE table.column='criteria'
AND table.column2='criteria2';
```